# JS Как получить base64 в bmp формате

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы получить base64 в bmp формате, т.к. при атрибутах `'image/bmp'` или `'image/png'` получаю в итоге строку для .png формата `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAH4AAAChC`

Все остальные форматы получаю без проблем кроме .bmp. Проверено в нескольких браузерах

Строку вытягиваю с помощью:

```
const str64 = c.canvas.toDataURL('image/bmp');
```

Comment: По стандарту браузеры не обязаны поддерживать другие форматы помимо PNG

Comment: Какие "Все остальные форматы..."? [Поддержка типов](https://kangax.github.io/jstests/toDataUrl_mime_type_test/)

Comment: [Canvas не может генерировать данные BMP изображения в Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652307/canvas-unable-to-generate-bmp-image-dataurl-in-chrome)